# Html email is getting unresponsive in gmail crome browser, works fine in gmail app and console in google desktop

Tags: html, gmail, html-email, responsive, responsive-emails

I am creating this email html template the html works responsively in google console and gmail mobile app, but gets distorted in mobile chrome gmail version.

This image is the mobile responsiveness when i open in console in crome desktop
[image]

this is email responsivness when i open in browser desktop
[image]

this is image responsiveness when i open in mobile browser
[image]

note this email template works fine in the gmail mobile app

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <title>pixels</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Objektiv+Mk1&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.c500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

        <style>
            @font-face {
                font-family: objektiv mk1;
                src: url(fonts.ttf);
            }

            * {
                font-family: objektiv mk1;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body style="margin:0; padding:0;">
        <div style="width:600px; margin:auto; overflow:hidden;  border: 1px solid #E5E5E5; background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/Y00Zyjrj/xxx.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 0px 91px; ">
            <table width="600px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="position: relative; border: none; ">
                <tbody>
                    <td style="padding: 20px;">
                        <table width="100%">
                            <tr style="text-align: center; width: 100%;">
                                <td style="text-align: center;">
                                    <div>
                                        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/fyVqfFC9/xxx-xxx-logo-green-410x.png"
                                        style="max-width: 150px;">
                                        
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="text-align: center; padding: 25px 0px 0px 0px; border-top: 2px solid #f4f4f4;">
                                    <div>
                                        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/X7p6s1qx/xxx-you.png" style="max-width: 350px;">        
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>

                    <tr>
                        <td style="background: #fff; font-size: 28px; text-align: center; padding: 20px 84px 30px;">for
                            ordering with us and taking the first step towards better health and wellness </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr style="background-color: #E5E5E5;">
                        <td>
                            <table style="width: 100%; padding: 40px; overflow: hidden;">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style=" background: #fff; overflow: hidden; border-radius: 5px;">
                                            <div><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/3wHMJKBb/process.png" style="margin: auto;"></div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="padding: 10px 0px;">
                                            <p style="text-align:center;font-size: 18px; font-weight: 600;">Your order will
                                                be dispatched within 48 hours. </p>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 26px 26px 0px;">
                            <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"
                                style="background-color: #EEFDEB;">
                                <thead style="background-color: #EEFDEB; margin-bottom: 10px;">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="width: 20%; padding: 10px; font-weight: 400; font-size: 18px;">Product
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width:24%; padding: 10px">&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td style="width: 20%; padding: 10px; font-weight: 400; font-size: 18px;">Qty</td>
                                        <td style="width: 20%; padding: 10px; font-weight: 400; font-size: 18px;">Price</td>
                                        <td style="width: 20%; padding: 10px; font-weight: 400; font-size: 18px;">Subtotal
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>

                                <tbody style="background-color: #E5E5E5;">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="height: 10px; background-color: #fff;"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="width:20%;">
                                            <div>
                                                <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/B6YwDsT3/xxx-eff.png"
                                                style="max-width:100%;">
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width:24%; font-size: 16px;">ACV <span
                                                style="display: block;">Effervescent</span< /td>
                                        <td style="width:20%; font-size: 16px;">{#var#}</td>
                                        <td style="width:20%; font-size: 16px;">{#var#}</td>
                                        <td style="width:16%; font-size: 16px;">{#var#}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="height: 10px; background-color: #fff;"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr style="background-color: #EEFDEB;">
                                        <td style="width:20%;">&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td style="width:24%; padding: 10px 0px; font-size: 16px;">Discount</td>
                                        <td style="width:20%;">&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td style="width:20%;">&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td style="width:16%; font-size: 16px;">{#var#}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr style="background-color: #EEFDEB;">
                                        <td style="width:20%;">&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td style="width:24%; padding: 10px 0px; font-size: 16px;">Discount</td>
                                        <td style="width:20%;">&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td style="width:20%;">&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td style="width:16%; font-size: 16px;">{#var#}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr style="background-color: #EEFDEB;">
                                        <td style="width:20%;">&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td style="width:24%; padding: 10px 0px; font-size: 16px;">Discount</td>
                                        <td style="width:20%;">&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td style="width:20%;">&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td style="width:16%; font-size: 16px;">{#var#}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td
                            style="padding: 26px; background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/RZfQd50z/1-Transactional-xxx-Order-xxx-svg-1.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 100% 350px; width: 100%;">
                            <table width="100%;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="">
                                        <div
                                            style="padding:0px 26px; background: radial-gradient(80.68% 88.46% at 50% 50%, #69DE7A 0%, #A9EF82 100%) #EEFDEB; border: 1.5px solid #000000; border-radius: 6px;">
                                            <p style="text-align:center; font-size: 24px; font-weight: 700;">Your cashback
                                                of {#var#} will be credited to your  wallet upon delivery!</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td
                                        style="border-bottom: 1.5px solid #969696; position: relative; top: 10px; opacity: 0.25;">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <div>
                                            <p style="font-weight: 600;">Shipping to:</p>
                                            <p style="margin:0;">{name}</p>
                                            <p style="margin:0;">{address line 1}</p>
                                            <p style="margin:0;">{address line 2}</p>
                                            <p style="margin:0;">{address line 3}</p>
                                            <p style="margin:0;">Tel. {phone number}</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td
                                        style="border-bottom: 1.5px solid #969696; position: relative; top: 10px; opacity: 0.25;">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td style="padding: 30px 75px 35px; font-size: 21px; text-align: center;">Check out our
                                        <strong>other best-sellers</strong> based on your purchase!
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="padding: 0px 40px 50px;">
                                        <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"
                                            style="padding: 10px 25px; box-shadow: 0px 2px 20px 14px rgb(64 60 67 / 16%); border-radius: 4px; background-color: #EEFDEB;">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="width:38%">
                                                    <div>
                                                        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/B6YwDsT3/xxx-eff.png.png"
                                                        style="max-width: 120px;">
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="width:62%">
                                                    <p
                                                        style="font-weight: 600; font-size: 15px; padding: 0 15px 0 0; margin-bottom: 0;">
                                                        Apple Cider Vinegar Effervescent</p>
                                                    <div><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/dQWKmcsL/star.png" /><img
                                                            src="https://i.postimg.cc/dQWKmcsL/star.png" /><img
                                                            src="https://i.postimg.cc/dQWKmcsL/star.png" /><img
                                                            src="https://i.postimg.cc/dQWKmcsL/star.png" /><img
                                                            src="https://i.postimg.cc/dQWKmcsL/star.png" /></div>
                                                    <div><a href="#"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/HsRDR07m/btn.png" /></a>
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>

                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td style=" padding: 0px 40px 50px;">
                                        <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"
                                            style="padding: 10px 25px; box-shadow: 0px 2px 20px 14px rgb(64 60 67 / 16%); border-radius: 4px;  background-color: #EEFDEB;">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="width:38%">
                                                    <div>
                                                        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/BZzVnSZc/xxx.png"
                                                        style="max-width: 120px;">
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="width:62%">
                                                    <p
                                                        style="font-weight: 600; font-size: 15px; padding: 0 15px 0 0; margin-bottom: 0;">
                                                        Ashwa Calm</p>
                                                    <div><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/dQWKmcsL/star.png" /><img
                                                            src="https://i.postimg.cc/dQWKmcsL/star.png" /><img
                                                            src="https://i.postimg.cc/dQWKmcsL/star.png" /><img
                                                            src="https://i.postimg.cc/dQWKmcsL/star.png" /><img
                                                            src="https://i.postimg.cc/dQWKmcsL/star.png" /></div>
                                                    <div><a href="#"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/HsRDR07m/btn.png" /></a>
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>

                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="padding: 0px 40px 50px;">
                                        <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"
                                            style="padding: 10px 25px; box-shadow: 0px 2px 20px 14px rgb(64 60 67 / 16%); border-radius: 4px;  background-color: #EEFDEB;">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="width:38%; padding: 0px 20px;">
                                                    <div>
                                                        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/pr3GGZc1/xxx.png"
                                                          style="max-width: 75px;">                                                    
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="width:62%">
                                                    <p
                                                        style="font-weight: 600; font-size: 15px; padding: 0 15px 0 0; margin-bottom: 0;">
                                                        Glutathione Skin Glow
                                                        Effervescent</p>
                                                    <div><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/dQWKmcsL/star.png" /><img
                                                            src="https://i.postimg.cc/dQWKmcsL/star.png" /><img
                                                            src="https://i.postimg.cc/dQWKmcsL/star.png" /><img
                                                            src="https://i.postimg.cc/dQWKmcsL/star.png" /><img
                                                            src="https://i.postimg.cc/dQWKmcsL/star.png" /></div>
                                                    <div><a href="#"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/HsRDR07m/btn.png" /></a>
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>

                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 25px;">
                            <table width="100%" style="border-radius: 5px; border: 1px solid #000; padding: 13px 25px;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="font-size: 20px; font-weight: 600;">Stalk us on our socials </td>
                                    <td style="text-align: right;">
                                        <table width="100%;">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="text-align: center;"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/Plixlife/"
                                                        style="line-height: 0; display: block;"><img
                                                            src="https://i.postimg.cc/HnPDpXZQ/xxx.png"></a></td>
                                                <td
                                                    style="border-left: 2px solid #000; text-align: center; border-right: 2px solid #000;">
                                                    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/myplixlife/"
                                                        style="line-height: 0; display: block;"><img
                                                            src="https://i.postimg.cc/wB5C1S4x/xxx.png"></a></td>
                                                <td style="text-align: center;"><a
                                                        href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCxjpQEVVTxs1P8i9x4KVoKQ/videos"
                                                        style="line-height: 0; display: block;""><img src="
                                                        https://i.postimg.cc/262gwnfP/xxx.png"></a></td>
                                            </tr>

                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of large images which are not responsive. You could consider putting `max-width:100%` on them.

Alternatively, you can fine-tune certain types of images by adding a class to the image and then using a media query. For example:

```
<style>
@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
  .small {
    max-width:100px!important;
  }
}
</style>

<img class="small" href="..." ...>
```

I also couldn't get it to be responsive in the browser without having the outer div `min-width:100%` (and no width or max-width set), and, the table `width:100%;max-width:600px;margin:0 auto`.

That will get it down to about 420px, but then it's just large tables that can't be made smaller. You could consider using a media query for making certain `<td>'s` have less padding on mobiles, and/or using a small font-size. Otherwise you will have to make your table differently.

Comment: This is not the issue because the emailer is fully responsive on mobile gmail and the images are looking perfectly fine but in mobile browser gmail(older version ) they are getting messed up. what could be the issue

Comment: Well, how can you be so sure about these things? Have you tested it? You asked for help, and this is frankly rude. Mobile gmail is not fully responsive - it's zoomed out a bit. Mobile browser supports less HTML and CSS than Android Gmail. It's also not centered on Gmail Chrome desktop (and possibly mobile), so you will need to do what I suggested there too. Why not give it a try?